# How to make cross site HTTP GET JSON request

Tags: json, angularjs, internet-explorer, http, cross-site

I am using AngularJS to make a cross site json call as following:

```
$http.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').success(function(response){
```

The above request works fine for Chrome and Mozilla Forefox, but it doesn't work on IE 9. IE 9 is the only version I've tested it on. I am assuming it wouldn't work on other IE versions either.

Could somebody tell me the mistake I am committing here for its not working in IE 9?

Comment: I tested it both on IE8 and IE9 works for me. Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets: On the console it just says `Error: Access is denied`.

Comment: did you able to fix the problem? or should i publish my answer ?

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets: I have not been able to fix this issue yet. I'll appreciate if you could post your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This is how I do it and this does not through any errors for me. Hope this can fix your problem.

//controller

```
(function() {
    var ipInfo = function($scope,IPService){
        IPService.ipServiceProvider()
         .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
       })
         .error(function(status,error){
           console.log(status);
           console.log(data);
       })
    };
    ipInfo.$inject = ['$scope',IPService];
    angular.module('app').controller('ipInfo',ipInfo);
}());
```

//services

```
 (function() {
    var IPService= function($http) {
        var urlBase = "http://ipinfo.io/json";
        var factory = {};
        factory.ipServiceProvider= function() {
            return $http.get(urlBase);
        };
        return factory;
    };
    IPService.$inject = ['$http'];
    angular.module('app').factory('IPService',IPService);
}());
```

Please let me know if you have any problems

Update : 
If you see this screen click on Yes. This usually pops up in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, getting that `Error: Access is denied` error on Internet Explorer. On chrome and Mozilla Firefox its working just fine. Following is how I am making that call. `.factory('ipinfoService', ['$http', function ($http) { var factory = {}; factory.findIPInfo = function() {         return $http({url: "http://ipinfo.io/json", method: "GET"})
.then(function(resp) { return resp.data; })        .catch(function(err) { console.log('Error during fetching ipinfo'); }); }; return factory; }])`. Just can't figure out the issue here.

Comment: I don't get any such message when I request the page. I just get a `Error: Access is denied` on the console. There has to be a way through programming for IE to neither neither showing that scary message nor giving `Error: Access is denied` on the console and somehow allow the cross-site requests work just fine, the way Chrome and Firefox allow.

Comment: Interesting, can you uninstall your IE and install it back?

Comment: But I could not ask the same to users using the application. Even if I get the message after re-installing IE it should not be showing me that message and just show me the result. There should be a fix for this for IE or I am not doing it the right way for IE.

Comment: Are users getting this message?

Comment: The app is not live yet. But they'd be either be my case(no message) or your case(message in pop up window), and I wouldn't want it to be either of them. There must be an IE way to do things properly.